# With Windows 7 Ultimate installed first on a single partition, what's the safest and best way to now dual boot Ubuntu 10.04 Server?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-7, installation, ubuntu-server

Title says it all. I've got Windows 7 Ultimate (32bit) installed on my machine, with one hard drive and nothing but the default partition. What is the safest way to now install Ubuntu Server 10.04 so that they coexist peacefully?

Comment: Is this question better suited on superuser.com? I suspect it will get moved there shortly.

Answer (score -1):

1. Install Ubuntu into VirtualPC
2. Use any partition resizer software to peacefully split existing patition.

Comment: The title says that he wants to dual boot fyi